# Really strange behavior creating a directory on SMB NAS share

Tags: macos, smb, nas

I am setting up a Synology DS918+ for backing up a new iMac Pro with an Drobo 5D3 attached to it.

I was working on backing up my Photos library from the Drobo using ChronoSync. ChronoSync was aborting with an error and after some debugging I can see what is happening, but its weird and I was hoping someone could help explain it.

To verify this is the issue I created a new SMB3 share on the Synology called Test and mounted it. Creating files and directories works as expected **unless** I create a directory named AUx.

```
$ ls -a
.       ..      .DS_Store
$ mkdir AUx
$ ls AUx
ls: AUx: No such file or directory
$ mkdir AUx
mkdir: AUx: File exists
$ ls -a
.       ..      .DS_Store   AHY9U3~9
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: This AHY9U~9 entry got created by mkdir?

Comment: Same here. If you create the folder via Finder instead of Terminal, it immediately gets renamed to "AHY9U3~9".  But in DSM's FileStation it is indeed named "AUx". Hard to say if the error is on Apple's or on Synology's side. Or if it an error in the first place, maybe just a reserved folder name for some reason?

Comment: Small update. Not only folders but also files with the name "AUx" (.txt) are displayed as "AHY9U3~9.TXT" in the SMB share. So maybe It is indeed a reserved string.

Comment: Yes, AHY9U~9 was created by executing mkdir. At least, I didn't run any other commands in the share except those in that snippet from bash so it must have been mkdir. And yes, I also see it as AUx if I look at it in DMS's file manager. It's not limited to mkdir, when ChronoSync creates the file the same thing happens, which causes the backup to consistently fail when getting to that directory.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue, and I'm so glad that I'm not alone! I solved it by mounting the drive using AFP instead of SMB, and that meant that I could see files called `AUX` again. (For various reasons, renaming the directory was not an option.)